# Why min function is not recognized by ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm using confluent to write a query to get the first timestamp in a 5 minute window of a kafka topic. Here's the query (I know it's not the pretty way to do it):

```
CREATE STREAM start_metric_value AS
select metric_value 
FROM dataaggregaion
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 MINUTE)
where metric_datetime_utc = MIN(TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(metric_datetime_utc, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) LIMIT 1;
```

but I have this error :

> Code generation failed for Predicate: Can't find any functions with
> the name 'MIN'. expression:(METRIC_DATETIME_UTC =
> MIN(TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(METRIC_DATETIME_UTC, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))),
> schema:`ROWKEY` STRING KEY, `ID` STRING, `METRIC_NAME` STRING,
> `METRIC_VALUE` STRING, `METRIC_DATETIME_UTC` BIGINT, `METRIC_INDEX`
> STRING, `IANA_TIMEZONE` STRING, `PROCESSED_DATETIME_UTC` BIGINT,
> `DATA_TYPE` STRING, `ASSET_TYPE` STRING, `ROWTIME` BIGINT, `ROWKEY`
> STRING Caused by: Can't find any functions with the name 'MIN'

can any one know how to solve this problem

Comment: It would help if you added details on the schema of `dataaggregaion`, and some sample into and required output.  This will help people understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear about what you're trying to achieve. See comment above on your question about adding more details to help people understand what you're trying to achieve.

That said, I can say....

The `Min` function is not being recognised for two reasons:

- You're passing the output of `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING` to `MIN`, but `MIN` does not take a string.
- You can't use a aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause.

The error message you're seeing looks like a bug. If it still exists on the latest version of ksqlDB you may want to [raise an issue in the ksqlDB GitHub project](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new/choose).

Even correcting these two things you're query will still fail as windowing in ksqlDB requires an aggregation, so you'll need a `GROUP BY`.

If, for example, you wanted to capture the min `metric_datetime_utc` per `metric_value` for each 5 minute window, you could do so with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE start_metric_value AS
  SELECT
    metric_value,
    MIN(metric_datetime_utc) as minTs
  FROM dataaggregaion 
  WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 MINUTE)
  GROUP BY metric_value;
```

This will create a windowed table, i.e. a table where the key is made up of `metric_value` and the `WINDOWSTART` time. `minTs` will store the minimum datetime seen.

Let's run some data through the query to understand what's happening:

Input:

```
rowtime | metric_value  | metric_datetime_utc
--------|---------------|--------------------
 1      |  A            | 3
 2      |  A            | 4
 3      |  A            | 2
 4      |  B            | 5
 300000 |  A            | 6
```

Output to the `START_METRIC_VALUE` topic might be (Note: metric_Value and windowStart will be stored in the Kafka record's key, while minTs will be in the value):

```
metric_value | windowStart | minTs 
-------------|-------------|------
 A           | 0           | 3
 A           | 0           | 3
 A           | 0           | 2
 B           | 0           | 5
 A           | 300000      | 6
```

What is actually output to the topic will depend on your value of `cache.max.bytes.buffering`. Setting this to `0`, turning off buffering, will see the above output. However, with buffering enabled some of the intermediate results may not be output to Kafka, though the final result for each window will remain the same.  You can also control what is output to Kafka using the upcoming [SUPPRESS functionality](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/design-proposals/klip-10-suppress.md)

The above solution gives you the min timestamp per metric_value. If you want a global minimum datetime seen per window, then you can `GROUP BY` a constant. Note, this routes all events to a single ksqlDB node, so it doesn't scale well as a solution.  If scaling is an issue there are solutions, e.g. like first calculating the minimum `metric_value` and then post-processing this to find the global minimum.

```sql
CREATE TABLE start_metric_value AS
  SELECT
    1 as Key,
    MIN(metric_datetime_utc) as minTs
  FROM dataaggregaion 
  WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 MINUTE)
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Note: syntax is correct for version 0.10 of ksqlDB. You may need to adjust for other versions.